# Making a basic block in Drupal 6

Tags: 6

I am trying to make a simple block to put out some HTML. However, my block is not showing.   This is what I have from putting it together from different pieces of code.

```
function blue_block_info() {
  $blocks['blue_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Blue'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function blue_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'blue_block';
      $block['subject'] = t('Blue');
      $block['content'] = blue_content();
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

function blue_content() {
  return '<div>this is a test</div>';
}
```

Comment: The answer given from Jimajamma is correct. Notice, anyway, that in your code you have `case 'blue_block';`. There should be a colon, not a semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are using above is for Drupal 7, not Drupal 6. In Drupal 6, it would be the following one.

```
function blue_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'list':
      // code from your blue_block_info()

    case 'view':
      // code from your blue_block_view()

  }
}
```